# Queries in Mongodb Gridfs - Metadata? Further Possibilities?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, metadata, gridfs

I started using MongoDB with Gridfs some time ago as I need to store documents that are bigger than 16mb. Saving and loading documents worked fine so far. 
Next, I wondered how to specify queries for my files stored in `GridFS`. Lets assume I have instances of my class which looks as follows:

```
public class Test {
  private String id;
  private int test;
}
```

If I want to query for a file which has a certain value for "test", how can I do that in GridFS? I know that I can save my file and store additional metadata. 
Hence, I could store the test value in the metadata of the file. 
To retrieve the value test of a file, I would do something like this:

```
String id = "...";
GridFS fs = new GridFS(mongoDB, "TESTFS");
BasicDBObject dbobj = new BasicDBObject();
dbobj.put("filename", id);
GridFSDBFile fsFile = fs.findOne(dbobj);

BasicDBObject metadata = (BasicDBObject) fsFile.get("metadata");
System.out.println("Test: " + metadata.get("test"));
```

Using metadata, is there an easier way to extract the "test" value of a certain file (without loading the complete file, deserialize the JSON string, etc.)

The disadvantage of this approach is that I have to store the metadata explicitly. If I want to query for other information, I need to introduce this into the metadata for all my data. Is this right?

Is there an alternative to storing such information in the metadata? Or how can I query for specific information in `GridFS`?
This is obviously a very simple example. The same questions arise when trying to perform more complex queries.

Comment: Yes - GridFS stores file metadata in a collection called `files` and the binary data in a collection called `chunks` (the names are configurable but these are the defaults). You can query `files` directly and, if you want, use the `_id`  to retrieve the whole file after looking at the metadata.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can I query for arbitrary information which is not explicitly stored in the metadata? Or is this not possible using GridFS?

Answer (score 0):

As @wdberkeley noted - you can query `db['fs'].files` explicitly without fetching the whole file each time (indeed, not the best idea). You can do it using find on the above collections (query as you would form it in MongoDB console - please translate to your language):

```
db['fs'].files.find({'metadata.test': '#### - the value you want to query for - $$$'})
```

The cursor that is returned in the MongoDB console and via most drivers is going to allow you to read metadata without ever retrieving the contents of the file.